# Инвалидация ключей в useInfiniteQuery (react-query)

Tags: reactjs

Не происходит повторный запрос для useInfiniteQuery. Можете подсказать в чем проблема?

```
const {
    data: data2,
    fetchNextPage,
    refetch,
  } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: [`NOTIFICATION_${statusSearch}`],
    queryFn: ({ pageParam }) => fetchNotification({ pageParam, statusSearch }),
    initialPageParam: 0,
    enabled: true,
    staleTime: Infinity,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
      return allPages.length;
    },

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: deleteNotification,
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [`NOTIFICATION`] });
    },
  });
  const deleteItem = () => {
    mutate(id);
  };
```